# link C++ static library on specified computer

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I developed a special business algorithm into a static library, and my other developers write non-critical code which will link to this static library when compile. I want to restrict only my company computer(Linux) can link this static library, to prevent this static library from being stolen and abused.

if not a good solution,any other suggestions is appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe require that in the app directory there is some special file with password that your static lib would read and check for content?

Comment: Prevent linking sounds impossible but you can integrate a license manager with your lib - e.g. do handshake with a server or read a license file tied to the executable.

Comment: can static library lock to MAC address? if match specified MAC, then let linker to link it into application, otherwise , print out error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very difficult to do this in a way that isn't easily bypassed by someone with some skills in doing such things. A simple solution would be to check the network card MAC-address, and refuse to run if it's "wrong" - but of course, anyone wanting to use your code would then just patch the binary to match their MAC-address. And you have to recompile the code whenever you use it on another computer.

Edit based on comment: No, the linker won't check the MAC-address, but the library can have code in it that checks the MAC-address, and then prints a message.

A more likely to work solution is to request permission from a server somewhere. If you also use some crypto-services to contact the server along with a two-part key, it can be pretty difficult to break. There are commercial products based on this, and it that didn't work, then they wouldn't exist - but I'm sure there are people who can bypass/fake those too.

As always, it comes down to the compromise between "how important it is to protect" vs. "how hard is it to break the protection". Games companies spend tons of money to make the game uncheatable and hard to copy, but within days, there are people who have bypassed it. And that's not even state secrets - government agencies (CIA, FBI, KGB, MI5, etc) that can have 100 really bright people in a room trying to break something will almost certainly break into whatever it is, almost no matter what it is - it just isn't worth the effort unless it's something REALLY important [and of course, then it is also well protected by both physical and logical protection mechanisms - you don't just log onto an FBI server from the internet, without some extra security, for example].

Comment: good point. I have thought this for long time and done some research. it seem that there is no simple way to prevent. thanks